# Broken links on api page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

Footer links on the API doc sites are broken:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

contains these broken links:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/about
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/faq
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/privacy

Remove the *api* prefix and they work fine.

Comment: The broken links are /about, /faq, /privacy. They don't work because they don't contain the domain name, and in the case of http://api.stackoverflow.com, or http://api.drupal.stackexchange.com, those links cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next build will fix these, /about and /privacy will point to the stackexchange.com pages.

/faq is being removed as it doesn't really exist (for the API), and API V1.x is deprecated so I don't think it's worth the effort of making one.